# How do I build my own android for the samsung galaxy

Tags: android

Is it possible for me to build my own version of android and put it on my samsung galaxy spica lite?
I would suspect that Samsung needs to put their drivers into open source since android is open source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a project for this called [GAOSP](http://code.google.com/p/gaosp/) where they are updating the Galaxy to Android 2.1. I'm not sure on the details of Samsung firmware updates, or the interactions, but they've got it all available via git from their [google project home page](http://code.google.com/p/gaosp/).

Answer (score 3):

You would need the available drivers for the device indeed but you are much more likely to find information via the AOSP.. I would recommend checking out XDA Developers and MoDaCo for creating compatible roms. There are a few developers at these places that are very familiar with making and deploying custom android builds.

Comment: Guessing that AOSP stands for Android Open Source Project